# How to add custom authentication logic to the Kong Plugin

Tags: api, api-gateway, kong, custom-authentication, kong-plugin

How do I integrate custom authentication service to Kong API Gateway, which redirects the call to different endpoint based on header or parameter validations and once authenticated should generate a token in the API Gateway. Is this possible in Kong plugin? Can you share any sample GitHub links related Kong?

Comment: The "first" or initial step of your authentication process could be covered by some of the already existing auth schemes that are supported by the "default" plugins (api key, basic, oauth, openid.... and so on)? if the answer is "yes", then you could move this custom logic to a separate plugin and configure both on your routes / services.